# Type Long in Oracle and C#

Tags: .net, oracle

I got this exception (Null Reference Object ) when I wanted to pass a very big C#  string (9KB) as a "long" parameter to an oracle stored procerdure , The problem occurred when doing "ExecuteReader" , can you help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad. Without further information the best solution is to mark it as a dupe of `what is an NRE`.

Comment: Try to avoid long type in oracle

Comment: "very big string" in Oracle= CLOB